# Autohotkey Multiple switch cases

Tags: autohotkey

How to make a different switches for checking.
In this code i want to make switch check the **wintitle** variable and **winclass** variable at once, look at the row **Switch (wintitle || winclass)**
This is the example:

```
WinGetTitle, wintitle, A
WinGetClass, winclass, A

Switch (wintitle || winclass)    ;;<<<<< Look at this row, How to set -
{                                           ;; - multiple variations for check ??
Case "Calculator":  ;;<< This is the %wintitle%
    WinActivate, %wintitle%
    send 5
    send {NumpadAdd}
    send 10
Case "ahk_class Notepad++":   ;;<<This shoud check %winclass% variable
    WinActivate, %winclass%
    send I am a bot
Default:
    msgbox,,, not found
}
```

Or i should write it as **&&** ??
Like this: **Switch (wintitle && winclass)**
Please explain the way how it does work

Comment: You can't do that. If you really want to do it this way, you could e.g. loop once and change the `SwitchValue` in-between.

Answer (score 0):

Switches are only for checking a single value, you can't check two values at once in them. For something more complex like this, you want to instead use if statements:

```
if (wintitle == "Calculator") {
    WinActivate, %wintitle%
    send 5
    send {NumpadAdd}
    send 10
} else if (winclass == "ahk_class Notepad++") {
    WinActivate, %winclass%
    send I am a bot
} else {
    msgbox,,, not found
}
```